# default date value of every Friday in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008 i want to set a default date value of every Friday to show up in the column when i insert a new record?

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT_NAME DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR myColumn
```

Whats the best way to show every Friday?

I want the default value to be based on the now date then knowing that the next available date is `05-07/2013`

I have the following:

```
dateadd(d, -((datepart(weekday, getdate()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), getdate())
```

But when passing todays date, it gave me: `2013-06-28` which is actually LAST Friday!, it should be the up and coming Friday!

Comment: So you want the Default Value of some column to be the nearest upcoming Friday?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998084/get-the-most-recent-fridays-date-sql

Comment: I want the default value to be based on the now date then knowing that the next available date is `05-07/2013`

Comment: thanks, made some edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-3, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, current_timestamp)+1, 0)) AS LastFridayDateOfWeek
```

Gets the last date of current week (sunday) then subtracts 3 from that to get Friday.

Replace `current_timestamp` if you need a different dates friday.

EDIT:
I thought about this a bit, and if the above (Friday THIS WEEK, so for Saturday it gives the previous date) does not work, you could easily use a reference date set like so:

```
DATEADD(DAY,7 + DATEDIFF(day,'20100109',@checkDateTime)/7*7,'20100108') as FridayRefDate
```

Same thing but with no hard coded Friday/Saturday in it:

```
DATEADD(DAY,7 + DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@checkDateTime),5),@checkDateTime)/7*7,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,@checkDateTime), 4))
```

So for 20100109 is a Friday.

```
SET @checkDateTime = '2012-01-14 3:34:00.000'
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,7 + DATEDIFF(day,'20100109',@checkDateTime)/7*7,'20100108') as FridayRefDate
```

it returns "2012/1/20"

But for `SET @checkDateTime = '2012-01-13 3:34:00.000'` it returns "2012/1/13"

Answer (score 1):

If your current query gives you *last* Friday, the easiest thing to do is simply to add 7 to it:

```
select dateadd(d, 7-((datepart(weekday, getdate()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 7), getdate())
------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  CONVERT(DATE, ( CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) - 6 <= 0
                             THEN DATEADD(dd,
                                          ( DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) - 6 ) * -1,
                                          GETDATE())
                             ELSE DATEADD(dd, ( DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) ) - 1,
                                          GETDATE())
                        END )) AS NearestFriday

Answer (score 0):

Just add 7 to the formula

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,CAST(5-GETDATE() AS int)%7,GETDATE()+7)
```

To verify the formula:

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT GETDATE() AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,d)
  FROM test WHERE d < GETDATE() + 30
)
SELECT
 d                                  AS [input],
 DATEADD(dd,CAST(5-d AS int)%7,d+7) AS [output]
FROM test
```

To tweak the the formula, adjust the 5- and the +7