# Finding specific day in month SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, sql-server-2016

I am trying to find a specific days within specific months for DST settings.  I found code from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794697/find-last-sunday).

```
SELECT
DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'19000107',DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()/*YourValuehere*/),30))/7*7,'19000107')
```

I also found this in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924777/how-to-get-last-day-of-last-week-in-sql) which could be used a month ahead.

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-1 - (DATEPART(weekday, @StartOfMarch) + @@DATEFIRST - 2) % 7,
           @StartOfMarch
          ) AS LastSunday
```

I am not great with SQL so I am looking for a dummy explanation of what is happening here, and why this code works.  From what I gather, Jan 07 1900 is significant in here as is the various built in date time functions. A simple play-by-play breakdown would help me understand what all is happening.

This is for the SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using? The linked post asks for solutions for SQL 2000 but there's been significant enhancements in handling date/time data in more recent versions. A little more detail on what you're trying to do would be useful too - which specific days in which specific months are you looking for? Cheers.

Comment: @GarethLyons ... updated the question.  Mainly I am looking at October and March, but in general I am looking for a good enough explanation so I can better grasp the concepts here.

Comment: What day of which month?  I don't understand what you want in the result set.

Comment: Oh... I am looking for the last Sunday of each month. Something that can be used to see if a particular date falls within the last Sunday of March through the last Sunday of October (British Summer Time).

Comment: Thanks. Jan 7th 1900 is used as it's know to be a Sunday. The rest uses the difference between that and GETDATE() or alternatively, /*Your value here*/ to work out the last Sunday of that particular month. But there's got to be better ways to do it in SQL 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since 2012 version there is a built in function to get the end of the month for any date / datetime value called [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql).
Using this function with [`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) and [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) is quite a simple way to get the date of the last sunday in any given month:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = GETDATE();
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EOMONTH(@Date)), EOMONTH(@Date)) As LastSundayDate
```

Result:

```
LastSundayDate
30.04.2017 00:00:00
```

Another example:

```
SET @Date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE());
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, EOMONTH(@Date)), EOMONTH(@Date)) As LastSundayDate;
```

Result:

```
LastSundayDate
26.03.2017 00:00:00
```

### Update

As SqlZim wrote in his comment, this relies on setting the first day of the month at sunday (using `set datefirst 7;` before using this query.

Comment: @SqlZim correct. Updated my answer to add a part referencing this.

Comment: @SqlZim correct. However currently I don't have the time to fix it, so I'll simply remove that part from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested, I'll often use a Table-Valued-Function to create dynamic date/time ranges.  A tally/calendar table would do the trick as well.  However, with a UDF, you can supply Date/Time Range, DatePart and Increment.

Also, being a TVF, it is easy to incorporate into a Sub-Query, Cross Join, etc.

In your case, if you are looking for the last Sunday in March and October

**Example**

```
Select D=Max(RetVal) 
 From [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2017-01-01','2017-12-31','DD',1)
 Where DateName(WEEKDAY,RetVal) = 'Sunday'
   and DatePart(MONTH,RetVal) in (3,11)
 Group By Year(RetVal),Month(RetVal)
```

**Returns**

```
D
2017-03-26
2017-11-26
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

Comment: This was suggested also by another developer here.  I believe there is something like this being used in a separate part of our application.  I might swing back around to this when we replace my quick fix with a real implementation.

Comment: Agreed on the reusable part.  I just transformed the smaller stuff into a function for yes/no.  It is how it is done already.  The code base is slated for refactoring so this may find its way in there.

Comment: @Branco Seems like you know what needs to be done.  inheriting someone else's work is always hard and very frustrating.